# Получить все IP адреса удаленных хостов с помощью Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Необходимо провести "инвентаризацию" серверов. Все сервера идентичны.

Задача 1:
Есть n серверов. На каждом сервере несколько IP адресов. Необходимо получить результат ip addr на каждом сервере.

Задача 2:
Получить виртуальные хосты на каждом сервере. (ls /home/usr/domain)

Задача 3:
Получить А запись для доменов, расположенных в /home/usr/domain/ и сопоставить их с IP адресами для каждого сервера.

Задача 4:
Подготовить 3 отчета:

```
  1. Имя сервера и список его IP адресов.
  2. Домены и их IP адреса, если IP адреса доменов соответствуют IP адресам наших серверов.
  3. Домены, чьи IP адреса не соответствуют IP адресам наших серверов.
```

Думаю для данной задачи использовать ansible, однако с ним никогда не работал. Подскажите каким образом лучше реализовать данные задачи? Возможно ansible позволяет сделать это "из коробки" или существуют подходящие расширения? Как лучше сохранять и обрабатывать результат выполнения скриптов?

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Первый пункт легко получается через https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html. Второй - если надо тупо список папок - то https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html. Третий - ну наверное https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/search.html?q=dns&check_keywords=yes&area=default, но не уверен.

Comment: Все ваши пункты сводятся к двум шагам - собрать факты и отфильтровать факты. Для этого в настройках ставте - хранить кеш в json, утилита для отчета `jq`. Могу написать подробный плейбук.